# How this service actually works. Trying to understand the code

Tags: angularjs

can someone please help me in understanding the following exception handling service.

```
angular.module('services.exceptionHandler', ['services.i18nNotifications']);

    angular.module('services.exceptionHandler').factory('exceptionHandlerFactory', ['$injector', function($injector) {
      return function($delegate) {

        return function (exception, cause) {
          // Lazy load notifications to get around circular dependency
          //Circular dependency: $rootScope <- notifications <- i18nNotifications <- $exceptionHandler
          var i18nNotifications = $injector.get('i18nNotifications');

          // Pass through to original handler
          $delegate(exception, cause);

          // Push a notification error
          i18nNotifications.pushForCurrentRoute('error.fatal', 'error', {}, {
            exception:exception,
            cause:cause
          });
        };
      };
    }]);

    angular.module('services.exceptionHandler').config(['$provide', function($provide) {
      $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', 'exceptionHandlerFactory', function ($delegate, exceptionHandlerFactory) {
        return exceptionHandlerFactory($delegate);
      }]);
    }]);
```

Comment: Did you see this commit: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/commit/7d615bb3e60f5a5b05b829addeb3b6c98820301e ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is a service interception. When you call $provide from a config block, you can use the "decorator" method to intercept a service. The first parameter to decorate is going to be the service you wish to intercept. In this case, the call is asking for the original $exceptionHandler service that is shipped with Angular.

The second parameter is an array of dependencies with a function that uses the dependencies. So, in other words, the dependency injection will parse the list of dependencies and pass it to the function that is the last element in the array.

In the case of decorator, the special dependency $delegate represents the service you are modifying. If you did this:

```
$provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
   return $delegate; 
}]);
```

You would basically just pick up the exception handler service and pass it right back.

Instead, the call is going into the exception handler factory. It is using a factory to defer loading of the dependency from the services.i18nNotifications module presumably because that also will reference the $exceptionHandler. The $injector allows lazy loading of a reference, so $injector.get() is getting something that was registered as i18Notifications.

What is happening is it is returning a function with the exact same signature as the built-in $exceptionHandler:

```
fn(exception, cause)
```

That function calls the original handler:

```
$delegate(exception, cause)
```

Then adds its own behavior that looks like it is creating an object with the exception and the cause and pushing it into the i18Notifications service.

```
i18nNotifications.pushForCurrentRoute('error.fatal', 'error', {}, {
   exception:exception,
   cause:cause
});
```

To make a short story boring, you are seeing service interception. An existing service is being intercepted to extend that service so it behaves as it did out of the box plus adds a new behavior to push the exception into the i18Notifications service.

More on decorator/service interception: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2014/01/interception-using-decorator-and-lazy.html

More on the $exceptionHandler: 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24exceptionHandler